# Variable = MAX() Causing Incorrect Syntax

Tags: t-sql

Have the following SQL below which will be part of a larger SP. I'm receiving a syntax error and I'm assuming it's due to the selected variable @ColumnMM containing a MAX function when trying to be executed withing the string of the variable @SQL. For example, changing Line 25 (@Column1) to
*SELECT @Column01 = 'abcd01' FROM MonthlySummary* works just fine.

How do I best resolve this?

```
IF OBJECT_ID('New_Report', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE New_Report
;

CREATE TABLE New_Report (
    Area NVARCHAR(255)
    , Division NVARCHAR(255)
    )
;

DECLARE @Column01 VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @Column02 VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @Column03 VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @Column04 VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @Column05 VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @Column06 VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @Column07 VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @Column08 VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @Column09 VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @Column10 VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @Column11 VARCHAR(6)
DECLARE @Column12 VARCHAR(6)
;

SELECT @Column01 = MAX(reporting_year)+'01' FROM MonthlySummary
SELECT @Column02 = MAX(reporting_year)+'02' FROM MonthlySummary
SELECT @Column03 = MAX(reporting_year)+'03' FROM MonthlySummary
SELECT @Column04 = MAX(reporting_year)+'04' FROM MonthlySummary
SELECT @Column05 = MAX(reporting_year)+'05' FROM MonthlySummary
SELECT @Column06 = MAX(reporting_year)+'06' FROM MonthlySummary
SELECT @Column07 = MAX(reporting_year)+'07' FROM MonthlySummary
SELECT @Column08 = MAX(reporting_year)+'08' FROM MonthlySummary
SELECT @Column09 = MAX(reporting_year)+'09' FROM MonthlySummary
SELECT @Column10 = MAX(reporting_year)+'10' FROM MonthlySummary
SELECT @Column11 = MAX(reporting_year)+'11' FROM MonthlySummary
SELECT @Column12 = MAX(reporting_year)+'12' FROM MonthlySummary
;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
;

SET @SQL = 'ALTER TABLE New_Report ADD ' + @Column01 + ' VARCHAR(6)';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

AND FYI -- The result of **SELECT MAX(reporting_year)+'01' FROM MonthlySummary** would be 202001. reporting_year is a VARCHAR(4) in MonthlySummary although I know that doesn't matter after using an aggregate function on it.

Comment: Don’t “assume”. Go to the *actual* failing line, isolated from the rest. This should be a 2-5 line reproduction (although the *actual* error can be distilled to one statement) and nothing extraneous.

Comment: Which error do you get exactly?

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '202001'.

Comment: Which has **nothing** to do with the MAX itself. Again, reduce it to the *actual* failing case/lines, which has nothing to do with the “assumed” error or relation to MAX. Stub in representative data, while removing each expression/line, to arrive at a minimal reproduction case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this link from the documentation:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15#rules-for-regular-identifiers

Basically, you can't use a digit character as the first character of a table name, column name, etc.

That aside, I also see a type mismatch problem. `MAX(reporting_year)` is a number, but `'01'`, `'02'`, etc are text, and so you need to cast to combine them together. Additionally, the code is unnecessarily repetitive, both in terms of how it's written and for the work it causes the server to do. There's no good need to run the same aggregation across the entire table multiple times.

```sql
DECLARE @MaxYear AS VARCHAR(4)
SELECT @MaxYear = CAST(MAX(reporting_year) As varchar(4)) FROM MonthlySummary

DECLARE @Column01 VARCHAR(9) = QUOTENAME('_'+@MaxYear+'01')
DECLARE @Column02 VARCHAR(9) = QUOTENAME('_'+@MaxYear+'02')
DECLARE @Column03 VARCHAR(9) = QUOTENAME('_'+@MaxYear+'03')
DECLARE @Column04 VARCHAR(9) = QUOTENAME('_'+@MaxYear+'04')
DECLARE @Column05 VARCHAR(9) = QUOTENAME('_'+@MaxYear+'05')
DECLARE @Column06 VARCHAR(9) = QUOTENAME('_'+@MaxYear+'06')
DECLARE @Column07 VARCHAR(9) = QUOTENAME('_'+@MaxYear+'07')
DECLARE @Column08 VARCHAR(9) = QUOTENAME('_'+@MaxYear+'08')
DECLARE @Column09 VARCHAR(9) = QUOTENAME('_'+@MaxYear+'09')
DECLARE @Column10 VARCHAR(9) = QUOTENAME('_'+@MaxYear+'10')
DECLARE @Column11 VARCHAR(9) = QUOTENAME('_'+@MaxYear+'11')
DECLARE @Column12 VARCHAR(9) = QUOTENAME('_'+@MaxYear+'12')
```

Finally, as a matter of good practice I object to naming the columns like this. If you want pivoted data, that's fine, but then let your client tool worry about the names and adjust as needed. Do this, and it's likely you can **significantly** simplify this entire procedure, possibly down the point of a single `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Oh, yeah. He can't have a leading number for an indentifier name. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-identifiers?view=sql-server-ver15#rules-for-regular-identifiers

Comment: This is part of the answer now.